# I can not figure out what the "is used to being" here mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

> Marie **is used to being** the queen bee within her circle of friends.

Is it a typo? Shouldn't it be like **used to be** or something?

Answer (score 3):

A synonym for **used** - as a predicate adjective, not a verb - is **accustomed**.

Thus:

> Marie is **accustomed** to being the queen bee within her circle of friends.

Comment: -Thanks a lot, and could you paraphrase the sentence, please? Is it saying that she accepted to be the queen and she is familiar and she welcomes this idea and all the complements from her friend?

Comment: I added an example.  It doesn't mean accepted/familiar/welcomes.  It means "expects and perhaps even feels entitled to".

Comment: @Codeswitcher, Thanks for the added example. My answer really wasn't complete without it.

Answer (score 0):

Each has a different meaning.

> Marie **is used to being** the queen bee within her circle of friends.

means she is the queen bee now, and has been for some time as she has become used to it. This meaning is similar to *accustomed*.

and

> Marie **used to be** the queen bee within her circle of friends.

means she used to be the queen bee, but is not now. *used to be* refers to what something was in the past.